# Adding cin in while loop to read multiple words from a single string input

Tags: c++, string

q.Write a program that uses an array of char and a loop to read one word at a time
until the word done is entered.The program should then report the number of
words entered (not counting done).

I want the count to increment until done is found in the string. I found a solution for this question online

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
using namespace std;

string word;
string matchword = "done";
int numwords=0;

cout << "Enter words (to stop, type the word done):\n";
cin >> word;

while(word != matchword)
{
    cin >> word;//how does it read the next word ????
    numwords++;
};

cout << "\nYou entered a total of " << numwords << " words.";

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

how does the cin read the next word of the string.My question basically is for someone to explain working of cin and string to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a delimiter, in order for you to be able to split the string and get the words within word.

The simplest thing for you to do is to create a word string array and collect the words entered(loop until word(N+1) is  "" or null. then you can iterate through the word array and list everyone word and you can get the count of how many words as well.

CIN explanation...(sort of)...
In your case cin is a pen and the string word is a white board.
You use cin to write things on word.
Everytime you use cin, you erase the white board and then write the new word.

Comment: The program listed above is working properly.I just want a good explanation regarding cin and string in the while loop.

Comment: The way the cin and word works within you loop is simple.. The loop goes round and round within its {}'s until while is false, once while becomes true than it will go to cout(because that is the next line). The CIN as I mentioned on my response, is like a marker and word is like a whiteboard; everytime the loop goes around the marker erases the whiteboard and writes something new and then the loop checks whats on the board to see if it is true or not, if it isn't the marker erases and then writes something else on the whiteboard.. and so on...

Comment: On another note, cin holds the information typed in from the keyboard the >> is what accutually "saves" that input into word... but once you get into overloading operators you will get the idea...(hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

From the link reference "cin" is used to take the value of input to "word" variable and it replace the value of "word" everytime so if the first word is "dog"      word =input="dog"
and if next word is "cat" the word=input="cat" not "dogcat" .Like it replace itselves everytime you press enter. Is this what you want from explanation?

Hope you understand

Poom

Comment: Also , using cin start a new line everytime for different input

Answer (score 0):

Every time in side the while loop you ask from the user to enter a word and **cin** replays the content of the **word** variable.